# How can I export my Tex document to fb2 format?

Tags: tex4ebook

I haven't found any receipt of exporting or saving Tex files to fb2. I would like to preserve everything I see in PDF and make it looking the same way.

UPD:
I tried an online converter from TEX to fb2 - it gives completely awful result! Either does PDF to FB2 converter. Layout is broken completely.
Also I tried to convert the file TEX with tex4ebook. It is very far from desired result. Onlu PDF direc compilation works for TEX files. It's very strange.

UPD2:
Also I have tried calibre convertion. It's okay with images ans fonts, headings are equal to PDF (which I converted from), but layout is broken: everything is aligned to the left side of a page. May be I should make some settings in calibre? I used heuristic conversion...

Comment: There are fb2 converters online. So there‘s certainly something you can install local with Linux.

Comment: If your document compiles with `tex4ebook`, you can convert the resulting Epub file using Calibre's `ebook-convert` command. Something like `ebook-convert sample.epub sample.fb2` seems to work. I am not sure how much formatting this format supports, but I wouldn't expect that the result will look in the same way.

Comment: How can I check whether my document complies with tex4ebook?

Comment: @NikolayYasinskiy try to compile it using `tex4ebook -m draft -a debug <filename.tex>`. If it compiles without errors, it should produce an Epub file.

Comment: It compiles without errors, but the result doesn't look like pdf